# How to create ArrayLIst<Object of my class>

Tags: arraylist

Hello so I am doing my first Java game. I have done some Scala Before. I am trying to do an ArrayList with instances of the class Questions I have done.

So I Have made a file with     `public class **Question** {stuff}`

And in Another file (but same package) I have made some instances of this class:

```
 Question question1 = new Question("Vad är 2+2","4","fyra","3");
 this I did for question2/question3/question4 aswell
```

And now I want to create an ArrayList with them as elements probably would work with an normal Array But I want to get to know the java ArrayList

I tried this:
    `ArrayList<Question> QAL = new ArrayList`
    `ArrayList(question1,question2);`
 and this:
    `ArrayList<Question> QAL = new ArrayList<Question>();`
    `QAL.add(question1);`

But neither works and the second one I found on an guide but for some reason it does not work. I would love any help I can get probably something really simple but I have struggled for a few hours now with this.

THanks- Le

Comment: For the second one you need to reference the list instance not the class. So, `QAL.add(....)`.

Comment: Oh sorry I wrote wrong but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the name of the ArrayList to add a object to list:
ArrayList QAL = new ArrayList(); ArrayList.add(question1); 
change to:
ArrayList QAL = new ArrayList(); QAL.add(question1);

Comment: I saw I wrote that wrong here on my post. But In my code I wrote like u said but I get this error :Error:(14, 12) java: <identifier> expected